# Trying to convert $interval with global vars to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code that I want it to repeat for several times with different attributes.

I'm using $interval from AngularJS and I'm not able to convert the piece of code into a function. Below I'll post both codes, the code without function and the code I tried with a function but gives error.

Original code

```
$scope.alarm.times.armed_away.pending_time = null;
var pendingTime;
var promiseAlarmPendingTime;

$scope.alarm.times.armed_away.pending_time = entity.attributes.armed_away_pending_time;

promiseAlarmPendingTime = $interval(function(){
   if($scope.alarm.times.armed_away.pending_time >= 0) {
      $scope.alarm.times.armed_away.pending_time -= 1;
      if($scope.alarm.times.armed_away.pending_time > 10) {
         playSound('audio/alarm_pending_time_1.mp3');
      } else if($scope.alarm.times.armed_away.pending_time > 0) {
         playSound('audio/alarm_pending_time_2.mp3');
      } else if($scope.alarm.times.armed_away.pending_time == 0){
         $interval.cancel(promiseAlarmPendingTime);
      }
   } else {
      $scope.alarm.times.armed_away.pending_time = null;
      $interval.cancel(promiseAlarmPendingTime);
      promiseAlarmPendingTime = null;
   }
}, 1000);
```

My try to make it work with function

```
promiseAlarmPendingTime = $interval($scope.fnAlarmPendingTime(
   $scope.alarm.times.armed_away.pending_time,
   promiseAlarmPendingTime), 1000);

$scope.fnAlarmPendingTime = function(pendTime, promise){
   if(pendTime >= 0) {
      pendTime -= 1;
      if(pendTime > 10) {
         playSound('audio/alarm_pending_time_1.mp3');
      } else if(pendTime > 0) {
         playSound('audio/alarm_pending_time_2.mp3');
      } else if(pendTime == 0){
         $interval.cancel(promiseAlarmPendingTime);
      }
   } else {
      pendTime = null;
      $interval.cancel(promise);
      promise = null;
   }
};
```

the function repeats itself 1 time and then gives an error:

```
TypeError: f is not a function
```

I also tried removing the entire code inside the function but the same error occurs. Maybe is some syntax problem?

Comment: You are calling `$interval` with the result of your function, not your function itself. First param must be the function, not the return of the function.

Comment: How do I achieve that? I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1) Call a function that calls your function and passes the parameters.
2) pass the parameters on your `$interval` call.

`$interval` has the following signature: `$interval(function, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [parameters])`. You already know what `function` and `delay` are - `count`, if set to a positive non-zero number, is the number of times the interval should run. `invokeApply` will wrap (or not) the `function` in a `$scope.$apply()` so that you can control dirty model checking which is what causes the view to update. Finally, `parameters` are the parameters you'd like to pass to your function.

**Example 1**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($interval, $scope) {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    let promise = $interval(() => incrementCounter(promise), 1000);

    function incrementCounter(promise) {
      $scope.counter++;
      if ($scope.counter == 10) {
        $interval.cancel(promise);
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Counter: {{ counter }}
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($interval, $scope) {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    let promise = null; // promise needs to be initialized before you can pass it as a parameter using this method
    promise = $interval(incrementCounter, 1000, 0, true, promise);

    function incrementCounter() {
      $scope.counter++;
      if ($scope.counter == 10) {
        $interval.cancel(promise);
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Counter: {{ counter }}
</div>
```

Comment: wow, worked with the first example. Thanks. But the first var passed in my code is dynamic, can be one or another, and then in the function I need to change that var and not store the value inside the function. Different variables names can be: $scope.alarm.times.armed_away.pending_time or $scope.alarm.times.armed_away.trigger_time, etc. Instead of pendTime in function I want the variable passed to be set.

Comment: The function is invoked on each iteration of `$interval` so if the parameters you are passing change the updated values will be passed. However, if they are `$scope`-level variables why even pass them to the function?

Comment: I declare $scope.pendTime (example) as 60 and pass it to the function, the function will subtract 1 every second to that variable until it reaches 0

Comment: Once you pass it as a parameter it becomes local to that function. If you are wanting to update `$scope.pendTime` then don't even pass it as a parameter. Just access it directly in your function.